# Secure Password Sent from Native App to HTTPS API

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest

I have a HTTPS API server, and want to connect to it from a native Android app (built in Cordova). The app uses is a simple XHR request like so:

```
function authenticate() {
  const username = document.querySelector('#usernameInput').value;
  const password = document.querySelector('#passwordInput').value;
  const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  const body = JSON.stringify({
    username,
    password,
  });

  xhr.open('POST', url, true);
  xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-type', 'application/json; charset=utf-8');
  xhr.onload = function () {
    console.log(this.responseText);
  };
  xhr.onerror = function () {
    alert('Request failed');
  };
  xhr.send(body);
}

function handleSubmit(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  authenticate();
}

document.querySelector('#submitButton').addEventListener('click', handleSubmit);
```

The request works fine and the username/password are authenticated on the server or 403 is returned. My concern is I can see the password in plain text if I look at the request payload in a local debugger. Does this mean passwords are exposed over the network? If so, what should I be doing differently?

Comment: https only encrypts in transit. The debugger will be storing info before it is sent. so it should be encrypted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using HTTPS only your computer and the server know the key to decrypt the data in the request, since they previously agreed on a key during the [key exchange phase](https://robertheaton.com/2014/03/27/how-does-https-actually-work/) of the SSL/TLS connection.

Other computers in your network should not be able to read your request's content since they don't have the key. You can see it in plain text in your browser's debugger because it **is** plain text **before** you actually send it.

Don't worry about manually encrypting your data before sending it to the server, the protocol already takes care of that.